# Problem building cython program under Windows

Tags: python, windows-xp, cython

I was starting to play with cython on my windows xp machine configured with Python 2.6. I tried to run the simple example on the Cython site but the conversion of the example .pyx file is immediately failing with a confusing error.

The .pyx file is

```
def say_hello_to(name):
   print("Hello, %s" % name)
```

setup.py looks like

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"])]

setup(
   name = 'Hello world app',
   cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
   ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

In a command window, I execute the command

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Note that all this is exactly what the webpage says to do.

As a result, I get the following output:

```
Error converting Pyrex file to C:
--------------------------------------------------------
...
def say_hello_to(name):
                      ^
--------------------------------------------------------
```

The error message says "Unrecognized characters".

I attempt the same example on a linux box and it works fine.

What is the problem here and why is a colon flagged as being unrecognizable?

Comment: Just a guess, but could it be having trouble with line endings? E.g. if the file has Unix `'\n'` line endings, but on Windows it's expecting Windows `'\r\n'` line endings?

Comment: That's it. My window's editor defaulted to '\r\n' but I can set it to be the linux '\n'. I re-ran the build and it works perfectly now.  Thanks, Thomas. BTW, I'd accept your answer except I don't see how to do it when it is in the comment portion.

Comment: I've reposted it as an answer if you want to accept it there ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Reposting as an answer because it apparently solved the problem)

Just a guess, but could it be having trouble with line endings? E.g. if the file has Unix `'\n'` line endings, but on Windows it's expecting Windows `'\r\n'` line endings?

OK, so it was the other way round. It expects `'\n'` line endings, and the editor converted them to `'\r\n'`.